# PL/SQL To Run Simple SQL Commands

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using basic SQL, I'm populating a table from another DB. This uses basic `Delete` statements to remove old data and `Insert` statements with a `FROM` clause using a DBLink. I'm attempting to transfer this to a package and have come up with this:

Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE LOADDATA AS 
  procedure POPULATETABLE;  
END LOADDATA;
```

PL/SQL (Package Body):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE BODY LOADDATA AS

procedure POPULATETABLE AS      
BEGIN

DELETE FROM DATATRANSFER;

INSERT INTO DATATRANSFER
   SELECT VALUENUM, DATACONTENT, sysdate AS TRANSFER_DATA
   FROM  TRANSFERTABLE@DATALINK;

COMMIT;

NULL;
END POPULATETABLE;
END LOADDATA;
```

And to run the command, I would run:

```
exec LOADDATA.POPULATETABLE();
```

My question is should the procedure have an input/output parameter or declared variables? It has compiled and worked correctly but I'm unsure if I'm following PL/SQL methodology.

Comment: You do not have to have input/output parameters or declare any variables unless needed.  DELETE FROM is logged.  I'm not sure if I would want that, if it's a table that can be reloaded from the remote source.  Of course, sometimes truncate isn't a choice without privileges.  Wasn't sure what the NULL; statement was about.

Comment: The null was provided as a template. I created through SQL Developer so it was there and I haven't removed it. It doesn't appear to be making a difference, should it be removed?

Comment: Sometimes a NULL; statement is needed where no code has been written yet, but the compiler expects a statement.   But in this example the NULL; statement serves no purpose.  I'd remove it.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after DELETE FROM DATATRANSFER. You might consider running a truncate instead of a delete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule to provide parameters.

Additonally you can insert record to log table which will store the start date, end date, number of records inserted and number of records deleted in case you need to track the batch execution periodically.

Also if this package is called by some web page or some application then you may need to create an exception block and send a Error Message as an output parameter in a User Readable Form.

EDIT:

Package Specification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE LOADDATA AS 
  procedure POPULATETABLE(out_variable OUT VARCHAR2);  
END LOADDATA;
```

Package Body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE BODY LOADDATA AS
procedure POPULATETABLE(out_variable OUT VARCHAR2) AS      
BEGIN
DELETE FROM DATATRANSFER
-- <TODO:INSERT records deleted and date into a log table>
INSERT INTO DATATRANSFER
   SELECT VALUENUM, DATACONTENT, sysdate AS TRANSFER_DATA
   FROM  TRANSFERTABLE@DATALINK;
-- <TODO:INSERT records inserted and date into a log table>
COMMIT;
NULL;
-- Assign out_variable as success if comletes successfully
out_variable := 'SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
-- WHEN OTHERS catches all exceptions Oracle error message is displayed in SQLERRM
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
-- Assign out_variable with Error message if errors out
        out_variable := 'Error :'||SQLERRM;
END POPULATETABLE;
END LOADDATA;
```

Comment: If the exception block is added, does that require an output variable? I read that there are different types of exception, so how can it be written to print all/any error that occur?

Comment: I have updated my answer with your sample code. Please check if it helps you.

Comment: Yes, it does. To run this, would this still work: exec LOADDATA.POPULATETABLE(); Or would I need to specify the output variable, how would that be written?

Comment: You need to pass a variable in the call statement : exec LOADDATA.POPULATETABLE(variable_name); The variable_name will contain the output message and this can be used to display in the parent webpage/form.